# How to send Date in json payload in jersey?

Tags: java, json, date, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I want to send java Date object in json format in YYYY:MM:DD HH:MM format. I've tried with java.sql.Date instead of java.util.Date. java.sql.Date does not have options for HH:MM so i can not use it. So i tried with custom message body reader shown as below.

```
public class DateMessageBodyReader  implements MessageBodyReader<Date> {

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType,
        Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return type == Date.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Date readFrom(Class<Date> type,
        Type genericType,
        Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders,
        InputStream entityStream)
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Date.class);
            Date date = (Date) jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller()
                .unmarshal(entityStream);
            return date;
        } catch (JAXBException jaxbException) {
            throw new ProcessingException("Error deserializing a Date.",
                jaxbException);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you want send payload from Jersey to another server, or Jersey receive data from client?

Comment: Format the `Date` object to a String pattern and send it in JSON. Don't forget to add Timezone to it if you are dealing with multiple locales in your program

Comment: @Manh Le jersey will receive data from client.

Comment: @Pat I want jersey to identify Date and serialize it.

Comment: Its seem ydk how to format `Date` value or you ydk how to receive the payload in Jersey?

Comment: @ManhLe I know how to receive payload in jersey. Even i received date with the use of java.sql.Date without any custom body reader.